# I can't visit my running container app on browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port

I am running docker-compose by creating 2 app, redis and simple node server, and docker-compose.yml is like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server: 
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis:/data
  node-server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4001:8081"
```

when I run the command `docker-compose.yml` it create 2 contaiers and the log says  `app is running on post 4001`
also when I run `dokcer ps` I see these containers

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                              NAMES
1c6872205ba3   redis:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 seconds ago   Up 12 seconds   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp             node_app_redis-server_1
9401443ab8c9   node_app_node-server   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 seconds ago   Up 12 seconds   5001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4001->8081/tcp   node_app_node-server_1
```

but still can't visit the app on `http://localhost:4001/`

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile? I think the error is coming you aren't exposing the port 8081

Answer (score 0):

as what @Nabil suggested, I wasn't exposing port 8081 in my index.js, so my app was listing on a different post than what is specified on docker-compose.yml file
so
------to reproduce the error-----

```
app.listen(4001, ()=>{
    console.log(`app is running on post 4001`)
})
```

where it should be port 8081 like this (error gone)

```
app.listen(8081, ()=>{
    console.log(`app is running on post 8081`)
})
```

by doing this I am able to visit my on `lcoalhost:4001`